# How to tell React to use another index

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I created an app with 
`react-create-app client`
inside my e-commerce website(it uses nodejs and express), in order to implement some other functionalities. The problem is that i don't understand how to make the react-app work with ejs template, instead of using index.html. First of all i want the root component to be in a .ejs file inside views folder(outside react app). I think i need to change something in webpack, but i'm really confused, i can't even find config and there are a lot of additional plugins and code that i've never seen before, it's really difficult to understand something. Also when i run my server on port 3000 and app on port 5000 (with proxy set on 3000) it says *'something already running on port 3000'*. What should i do? I can't use react on the entire website (all buttons, menus) because it's too simple for react i think, and there is some simple rendering done with ejs that i don't know how to implement with react.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first you shouldn't use `create-react-app` for just bunch of components on existing page, this is whole environment done for true SPA done purely in React. If you need to just plug React to the existing page you have no choice than to read docs and learn or find a way how to setup in your existing app (you didnt say anything about it so I am not answering how.)

Secondly you need to `eject` your react app with `yarn eject` which will expose you all configs. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject

Then you need `html-webpack-plugin` which can accepts `.ejs` format as entry point https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin.

I don't see any reason why not to use `React` for everything, because it is "too" simple. You can render plain HTML with PureComponents and it will cost almost 0 memory for browser to render it.